# Getting a strange Rabbitmq error when I start my Spring Boot server

Tags: java, api, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am trying to create a Spring Boot endpoint that consumes a message from a queue, this is my code:

```
@PostMapping("test")
@RabbitListener(queues = "test-queue")
public String test(@RequestBody String body, String in) {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    AmqpAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    admin.declareQueue(new Queue("test-queue"));
    return in;
}
```

However, I get a really strange warning when I start the Spring Boot application:

```
2022-05-20 14:58:40.713  WARN 78294 --- [92.168.1.3:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occurred (Exception message: Socket closed)
2022-05-20 14:58:40.719  WARN 78294 --- [e01:f475%4:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occurred (Exception message: Socket closed)
2022-05-20 14:58:40.726  WARN 78294 --- [e01:f474%5:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occurred (Exception message: Socket closed)
2022-05-20 14:58:40.730  WARN 78294 --- [dc:4823%12:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occurred (Exception message: Socket closed)
2022-05-20 14:59:40.769  WARN 78294 --- [80:5beb%14:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occurred (Exception message: Socket closed)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to the fact that you are listening on the wrong port or a firewall is blocking your connection. Make sure your RabbitMQ broker is up and listening on port 5672 and that the firewall allows tcp connections to that port.

Comment: I don't think that it is related to firewall. The broker is up and listening on 5672

Comment: The `@RabbitListener` on the `@PostMapping` is not OK. Do you really expect to listener for the HTTP request and AMQP queue in the same method? The `body` is indeed a request body, but which param is for an AMQP message payload? Also return `String` is going to trigger a reply message process. Queues can be declared automatically when they are beans and there is an `AmqpAdmin` bean. But again: the problem you describe has nothing to do with your code. It is just a fact that there is no connection to your RabbitMQ broker.